# local react project migration to codesandbox.io

Tags: reactjs

I want to migrate a local project (hosted local via npx on apache) to codesandbox. But I have some difficulties.

This is the project on codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/weather-app-p4h0u

This is the local code at Github: https://github.com/bastian-84/weather_app_1

I checked:

- Dependencies in package.json
- File structure in general

The errors I get are:

- When I load the page the ${} variables are not shown. But no error messages.
- When I search for a city in the form input field I get those error messages:
- "Network Error"
- in ./src/App.js at line 76 Axios.get( ) wont work.
- stack frames were collapsed

I guess I do some fundamental error.